# CV contents for application for professorship positions in Germany

Tags: career-path, job-search, faculty-application, germany

I am in the process of applying for a Junior Professorship (W1) in mathematics in Germany, and according the the job listing, the required application documents include a CV and a list of publications (among other things).

What should I include in the CV? Personal details, such as date/place of birth, martial status? How about invited and contributed talks at workshops and conferences? And research interests, or language / computer skills?

How long should the CV generally be?

Comment: Read the full advert. Typically, the university page might have more details than your source of the position. In most cases they list exactly what they want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- In Germany you usually have data/place of birth and martial status on your CV and it is also common to have the number of children there. Also a portrait photo is not uncommon, though not necessary.
- You should state your **academic career**, i.e. where you got your degrees, who has been your supervisor and when you graduated (give BSc, MSc and PhD).
- **Academic and other employments** (where did you do postdocs, internships and such)
- A list of **grants**.
- **Other scientific activities** such as service for the community, public outreach, acting as a referee for journals.
- **(Invited) talks** you gave (may be a selection)
- **Lectures** you gave, possibly your **graduate students**

That's what I had on my CV when I applied for Junior professorships. Was about five pages without list of publications (which can be included in the CV, by the way).

Comment: Is there a motivation to include data/place of birth and martial status on CVs in Germany?

Comment: I am not sure… people also count the "academic age", i.e the lifespan after obtaining the PhD (for which the actual date of birth is not needed). Actually, you could omit all these, but since everybody is used to seeing them on applications, people may start thinking when they do find these dates in your application.

Comment: I'm shocked at the suggestion that an academic CV might _exclude_ a complete list of publications.

Comment: If it is not included it has to be submitted separately. So don't be shocked no more.

Comment: @JeffE Also in Italy you are usually required to submit the list of publications separately from the CV, because publications are evaluated in a specific section of the selection, and the committees want to find them easily.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer, 5 pages is quite a bit longer than I would have expected. I have seen some people also include things like language and computer skills, how about those?

Comment: If you are not a native speaker, then definitely give your language skills. You may also add language skills also as a native speaker and also computer skills would not look strange but I guess that the commission will not really care.

Comment: @user2768 Tradition. But it is getting way less common. Neither my (academia) nor my dads (industry) current CV include any of this information. (We are both Germans in Germany). I have a pretty standard academic CV, nothing specifically German on there.

Comment: @skymningen, I wonder if anti-discrimination law has led to such information becoming less common.

Comment: @user2768 I have seen companies ask for the information to not be provided to prevent them from any blame. But as far as I know it's more that people are not willing to include it. For tax reasons, if you get employed your employer will anyway get to know all of this.

Comment: @user2768 Age (and, to a lesser extent, citizenship) becomes relevant if the position is that of a civil servant (which professor position usually -- but not always -- are). In principle, that shouldn't be the committee's business, but the date of birth is usually on the diplomas you have to submit anyway. Marital status is of interest to the committee in gauging the likelihood of your actually coming but really none of their business; it's getting more usual to be omitted.

Comment: @user2768: "Is there a motivation to include data/place of birth and martial status on CVs in Germany?" - as often in this kind of processes, the readers aren't deeply interested in the information itself (IMHO, knowing e.g. about the place of birth is at best useful as an "ice-breaker" in the interview), but just in the question "Is the candidate familiar with professional conventions for what belongs into such a document?"

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to the great answer by @Dirk, it is also helpful to include a couple of references, who the viewer can contact to verify you. It is also common practice to include Zeugnisses (work certificates) in the application package, but not in the CV itself.

Comment: "Zeugnisses (work certificates)" what do these contain?

Comment: It is a certificate given by your employer when you leave, which states the period you worked, what your responsibilities were, and how satisfied the employer was with your performance. Be warned though, employers in German-speaking countries are generally not allowed to write 'bad' Zeugnisses, so there is a lot of reading between the lines involved in these documents.